# Reactjs: setTimeout not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to execute a function only after 5 seconds, but it execute immediately upon render

Below is my code

```
class App extends React.Component {
  onInactive = (ms, cb) => {
    var wait = setTimeout(cb, ms);

    document.onmousemove = document.mousedown = document.mouseup = document.onkeydown = document.onkeyup = document.focus = function () {
      clearTimeout(wait);
      wait = setTimeout(cb, ms);
    };
  };

  render() {
    this.onInactive(5000, alert("Inactive for 5 seconds"));
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is my codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-currying-e02tc?file=/src/App.js:153-716)

Comment: The quick fix is `this.onInactive(5000, () => alert("Inactive for 5 seconds"));` (to wrap the `alert` in a function) but this is still _very_ bad use of React.

Comment: `setTimeout` expects a function as its first argument (or a string, but please don’t pass strings). `alert("Inactive for 5 seconds")` isn’t a function.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the second parameter is not a function, it's a statement, but setTimeout function expects the first parameter a callback function.
Please check the below-working code for it.

```
import React from "react";

/**
 * Add any other events listeners here
 */
// const events = ["mousemove", "click", "keypress"];

class App extends React.Component {
  onInactive = (ms, cb) => {
    var wait = setTimeout(cb, ms);

    document.onmousemove = document.mousedown = document.mouseup = document.onkeydown = document.onkeyup = document.focus = function () {
      clearTimeout(wait);
      wait = setTimeout(cb, ms);
    };
  };

  render() {
    this.onInactive(5000, () => alert("Inactive for 5 seconds"));
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Not a statement; it’s just `undefined`.

Comment: Right, What I meant is, it has to be a function in order to execute since setTimeOut first parameter expects to be a function